# spring cloud multiple binding not working in 3.2.2 jar

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to send json(topic-json) and avro(topic-avro) messages to multiple topics with Avro input message. I am getting application.yaml error when I set "binder" with value i.e. binder: kafka-1-with-ssl. I am also using below jars:

```
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams",-->3.2.2
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka",-->3.2.2

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.1"
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in below yaml file.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: processor
      bindings:
        processor-in-0:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: input-topic-in-avro
          consumer:
            use-native-decoding: true
        processor-out-0:
          binder: kafka-1-with-ssl
          destination: topic-json
          content-type: application/json
          producer:
            use-native-encoding: true
            key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
            value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
        error-out-0:
          binder: kafka-2-with-ssl
          destination: topic-avro
          content-type: application/json
          producer:
            use-native-encoding: true
            key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      binders:
        kafka-1-with-ssl:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
              auto-create-topics: false
              brokers: <broker-name>
              configuration: # Common properties for SSL...
              producer-properties:
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                value.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
        kafka-2-with-ssl:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      auto-create-topics: false
                      brokers: <broker-name>
                      configuration: # Common properties for SSL...
                      producer-properties:
                        key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                        value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
                        schema.registry.url: <registry-url>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is without knowing more details. I noticed that the `streams.binder` section of your config does not match with anything and seems like that is placed at the wrong place.

Comment: i have removed stream.binder. This one i need for me to consume the message (streaming). it seems like i am able to send the json or avro message but my intellij workspace still showing me red color with "invalid value  kafka-2-with-ssl or kafka-1-with-ssl"

Comment: That could be an IDE issue. Do you run into issues when running the app?

Comment: no. let me see if i can use another IDE. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: have you solved problem?